# Run Custom HTML5

Tags: html5

How do I upload and run a reveal.js presentation on WordPress? I have have been searching a lot to find the steps but I don't even know where to start. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about `reveal.js` other than what I just googled, but you can copy/paste a `page.php` from your theme and name it `page-{slug}.php` for a specific page then add any code you want into the content area of the page.

Assuming your theme doesn't break this format in any way. Instructions on making a page template can be found [in the WP developer site](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/)